# GetValue of a property

Tags: c#, sql-server, properties

I have a table in an MSSQL database with ~300 columns and I want to extract only one row and get all the values of the columns. I've used this code but I have problems with `GetValue(,)` method. This is my code:

```
private PropertyInfo[] GetValuesDB()
{
   ......
   var result = from val in datacTx.TableA
                where val.A == "AA" + "-" + "11" &&
                      val.B == "CC                   
                select val;
   return result.First().GetType().GetProperties();
}

...
public void MethodA()
{
  var res = GetValuesDB();
  foreach (var propertyInfo in res)
  {
    var rez = propertyInfo.GetValue(res,null);
  }
}
```

I always obtain this kind of exception:

```
Object does not match target type.
```

Comment: i think you forgot one " after CC

Answer (score 3):

`GetValue` expects the type of the first argument to be the type declaring the property (or a subtype).

So your `result.First()` call returns a reference to an object - and you want to get the properties *on that object*... so that should be the reference you pass to `GetValue`. You'll need to change your code to return that reference:

```
// Ideally, change this to a more appropriate return type...
private object GetValuesDB()
{
   ......
   var result = from val in datacTx.TableA
                where val.A == "AA" + "-" + "11" &&
                      val.B == "CC"
                select val;
   return result.First();
}

...
public void MethodA()
{
  var res = GetValuesDB();
  foreach (var propertyInfo in res.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    var rez = propertyInfo.GetValue(res, null);
  }
}
```

So `GetValuesDB` now returns a reference to the relevant entity - and *then* you fetch the property descriptors, and ask each descriptor for the value of that property *on that object*.